# PHP Class error

Tags: php

I am getting the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}'

The referenced lines are:

```
class Food {

private $q = array();   
private $nutrients = array();

...
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What version of php are you using? What line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: The quoted lines are fine. Parser errors are never accurate, try posting a bigger excerpt that, when saved and executed in a file of its own, results in the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can only use "private" in a php 5 environment. It looks like you're running that in PHP 4.

Comment: I double-checked what version of PHP I was using, and it was PHP4! I switched it to PHP5 and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing an ending curly brace '}'. (at least you did in the provided code).

But it's hard to tell with as less code as you provided. Please provide more code on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Food {

private $q = array();
private $nutrients = array();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be caused by a string that is declared further on in your class somewhere outside any function calls or variable declarations.

Another likely cause is a missing semicolon on the end of one of your declarations.

Can you please provide more code (including the offending line number).